# How can I restart my OneDrive App from Terminal / Command Line?

Tags: macos, command-line, microsoft

I use OneDrive on my Mac devices - iPad, iPhone, iMac, mini, and MacBook (iOS 16 and various versions of macOS from Catalina to Ventura).  Without fail, the OneDrive app on the Mac computers will just stop syncing.

The fix is to restart the App.  When I am using the GUI, this is easy, but when I am remote (usually connected via SSH), there’s no easy way to restart the App short of rebooting.  Is there.  Is there a command line command to restart OneDrive?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but could it be that the files on your Mac have illegal characters in the filename, which OneDrive silently refuses to sync? I thought of that as I stumbled on [this script earlier](https://github.com/soundsnw/mac-sysadmin-resources/blob/master/scripts/fix-onedrive-filenames-apfs.sh) which aims to resolve that.

Comment: I don’t have any files like that @SaaruLindestøkke.  I make certain to use only valid characters for my files and OneDrive doesn’t give any errors.  It will error out (in the GUI) giving you a list of files that couldn’t sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to be able to simply reset the service with a command, but this requires killing the app process(es) and then restarting.  I create a function which can be added to your `.zshrc` or `.zprofile` (or `.bashrc` or `~.bash_profile`).

```
resetOneDrive () {
    ps -ef | grep OneDrive | grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs kill -9
    echo "Waiting for services to finish..."
    sleep 2

    echo "Restarting OneDrive..."
        
    open -jg /Applications/OneDrive.app
}
```

The script is pretty simple.  It looks for all processes with the term “OneDrive” (excludes the `grep OneDrive` process) and kills them with a `-9` signal.  It then sleeps for two seconds to allow the processes to finish and PIDs to be removed.  Then it starts the OneDrive app.

It requires `sudo` privileges ; it will ask you for your password at execution.

When you put this in your login file, be certain to re-source it so the changes are immediate (or close/reopen your Terminal).  Just issue the command `. ~/.zshrc`, for example, if this is where you put the function.

Comment: You probably could just `sudo pkill -9 OneDrive`, or at least `ps -ef | awk '/[O]neDrive/ { print $2 }' | xargs sudo kill -9`.

Comment: I’ll give that second  command a shot @nohillside.  I initially started with the `pkill` but it just didn’t kill both processes.  I’m not sure why.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, forgot the xargs in the second version, but I'm sure you figured that out yourself :-)

Comment: I don't have OneDrive on my Mac right now, but [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/onedrive/comments/xp1l93/how_can_i_run_the_onedriveapp_commandline_on_macos/) suggests you can use CLI switches with the OneDrive executable, e.g. the `/shutdown` switch. Perhaps that's more elegant than killing the processes?

Comment: Those are Windows conventions (the slash), not *nix.  The person replying was giving their experience based on Windows.

Comment: Too bad, I thought because the `/getpin`  command [is a Mac command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/files-on-demand-mac) the `/shutdown` might work too.

Comment: The slash (`/`) before the command or arguments indicates a path.  For program arguments using flags, *nix uses a single or double dash (`-` or `—`).  In windows it would be `ipconfig /all` and the same command in macOS/FreeBSD/Linux is `ifconfg -a`. Using the slash in *nix would be something like `open /foo/bar/foobar` open the file at that particular location.

Comment: The Microsoft web page states clearly that the command does expect `/getpin`, etc. on a Mac.  I agree it doesn't follow *nix conventions, but we can't expect that from MS, can we :)  Sadly the `/shutdown` doesn't work and, even sadder, I don't have a better answer for your question :(