# Why OneDrive for Mac is "Waiting to Upload" indefinitely on some new files instead of uploading them?

Tags: onedrive

With my MacBook I make notes in plain MarkDown text files and keep them in OneDrive folder expecting them to be always synched with the cloud.
Yesterday, when I was reviewing my notes on another device, I found out that not all of the notes I made recently are present in OneDrive cloud.

If I switch Finder to "as List" view on my MacBook, on some files I can see a cloud icon made with dotted lines, and if I hover the muse on the cloud icon, it says: "Waiting to Upload".

[image: Waiting to Upload]

This dotted-lines cloud icon exists exactly for those files which for some reasons did not reach the OneDrive cloud yet.

I am very surprised by this behavior, because I expect each file I put into OneDrive folder to be automatically synchronized with the cloud. What is it "waiting" for?

At the same time, if I click on OneDrive icon in menu bar, there is some kind of log about recent files, and I clearly can see that one of the files which has dotted-lines cloud icon is reported as "**Uploaded to** %DESTINATION_FOLDER_NAME%" (as if it was really uploaded on the day when the file was created)

[image: Uploaded to]

By experiment I've learned, that if I double-click the file with the dotted-lines cloud to open it, it immediately synchronizes with the cloud, and in the menu bar log I can see "Uploaded to" for this file again (this time "uploaded-for-real", after I double-clicked on it to open it).

Any explanation, why OneDrive for Mac does not behave as I expect and is "Waiting for Upload" indefinitely instead of automatically uploading a new file instantly? Is it in conflict with Apple's similar iCloud feature? I do not think so, because iCloud should be turned off, I never used it.
Also, my setup is quite simple: the system is quite fresh and OneDrive (currently v23.132.0625) was installed with App Store.

The worst thing here is that I recently did a hard-reset of my MacBook without knowing that OneDrive's "Waiting for Upload" behavior and lost my data.

Comment: OneDrive get’s hung up for various reasons.  Try [resetting the daemon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/461531/119271) and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: @Allan system reboot does not help. Opening file with text editor does not help too. Only double-clicking file with Finder works and files gets instantly synched

Comment: That would indicate a potential sync conflict which is resolved by Finder accessing the file.  Next time you get this, try issuing the Terminal command `touch <filename>` and see if it syncs after.

Comment: @Allan, thank you! `touch` works, but still I understand the root cause of the problem, because I do not use iCloud ‍♂️

Comment: iCloud isn’t related here. What appears to be happening is that OneDrive can’t determine which version is the most recent.  By `touch`-ing the file, macOS changes the last modified date and thus this becomes the version to be synced.